# Modify Result Layout - Global Search for User

Tags: global-search

Is there a way to customize the search result columns for user/people. Salesforce provides the people Name and option to follow the user. I have tried modifying the search layout for user.
Can we add more columns here. I couldn't find the standard .. Is there any hack that can be done.. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth. It doesn't seem like you can.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KWwYAAW